# I'm trying to read only the first 3 chars from a file - c

Tags: c, string, file

Hi I'm building an app which will check the numbers in the file are all fixed, and if not - to fix them (Depending on specific country codes).
In order to check if the number is good I first need to look at the country code, and for that I need to read the first 3 chars (From a phone number in file) to see if the number even have a country code.
When I'm running the code below I'm getting

> Stack around the variable 'country_code' was corrupted".

I think my reading the specific 3 char from the string is making the problem, but I can't find what exactly is doing it.

```
void fix_file_il_country(char *filename)
{
    FILE *f = fopen("1.txt", "r");                  //The file to check from
    if (f == NULL)
    {
        printf("EROR\n");
        return;
    }
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "w");                //The new file with fixed numbers
    if (f == NULL)
    {
        printf("EROR\n");
        return;
    }
    char num[20];
    char country_code[3];
    fscanf(f, "%3s %s", &country_code, &num);
    while (!feof(f))
    {
        if (strlen(num) == 12)
            if (country_code == "972")
                fprintf(fp, "%s\n", num);
        fscanf(f, "%3s %s", &country_code, &num);
    }
    fclose(f);
    fclose(fp);
}
```

The numbers like: 9725XXXXXXXX should be written the new file
Numbers like: 123XXXXXXXXX, or number with more\less chars than 12 shouldn't been written.

Comment: Please show some pairs of sample input and desired output. Contrast it to the output you actually get.

Comment: Please upgrade your code quote to a [mcve].

Comment: Also, the arrays decay to a pointer to the first element, hence `fscanf(f, "%3s %s", country_code, num);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't provided space for the null terminator.

```
char country_code[3];
```

should be

```
char country_code[4];
```

Also, see [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong)

Answer (score 1):

I can see two potential issues:

1. the `char` array needs to store also the null termination, so it should be defined as

   ```
   char country_code[4]
   ```

   otherwise it is not possible to define the end of the array.
2. In the `scanf` you are passing the pointer of a pointer. You should change

   ```
   fscanf(f, "%3s %s", &country_code, &num)
   ```

   to

   ```
   fscanf(f, "%3s %s", country_code, num)
   ```

   without the `&`.

Comment: As both comment above said, I needed to add another space at the string for it to work.